# Move sheet to workbook with a given variable name and variable sheet count

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro that will move a worksheet (`order_line_list`) from its workbook to a position after the last sheet of another workbook (`Accrual Planning by Month 2020`).

The Accrual Planning by Month workbook file name isn't constant, so I have set it up as a variable in the code. The last sheet of that workbook will also change every month as a new sheet is added.

I can get the macro to work if I use the full file name and specify a sheet position (after sheet 2). However, if I try to do it with the file name and sheets count variables, I receive a the following error:

```
Run-time error 1004: Move Method of Worksheet Class Failed
```

I tried to use the Copy method instead, but I just receive the same Method Failed error.

I have spent multiple hours researching and trying to figure this out, but have not been able to. I'm new to VBA so there is likely a much simpler way to do what I am trying to do. Below is my code. I have files but can't seem to figure out how to attach them. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Function wbname(MatchName As String) As String

   Dim wb As Workbook

For Each wb In Workbooks

   If wb.Name Like MatchName Then

    wbname = wb.Name

    Exit Function

  End If

Next wb

   wbname = ""

End Function

Sub Macro302()

' Move Sheet to Accrual Planning by Month file

Accrual = wbname("Accrual*")

Windows("order_line_list.csv").Activate

    Sheets("order_line_list").Move After:=Workbooks(Accrual).Sheets.Count

    'Sheets("order_line_list").Copy After:=Workbooks(Accrual).Sheets.Count

'Windows("order_line_list.csv").Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: You would need `after:=Workbooks(Accrual).worksheets(Workbooks(Accrual).Sheets.Count)` but not sure if your function will work - not sure you can pass the asterisk.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly what I was missing!